# having the store version and development version installed side by side on my iphone device

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, multiple-versions

I have an iphone app in App Store, its installed on my device for demonstrations.
I'm also developing the next version and need to see how it runs on my device, not just in simulator, but when connecting the device for debug with xcode, the store version get's overwritten. This behavior results in multiply uninstall & install of the application from the store which is bad for app rating (apple algorithm takes uninstall into account).

Is there a way to have both version running on the same device?

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily change the Bundle ID on your Xcode Target (or make a new Target whose only difference is the testing Bundle ID) to allow side-by-side testing of a test app with an App store app.  The two apps won't share their data.  Something like: com.sample.mycompany.myappstoreapp.testversion123

Don't forget to change the Bundle ID back when you are done side-by-side testing and want to submit or distribute the app.

Comment: * when trying to change the bundle id at xcode->targets->general-> bundle id I can't add more than 6 characters to the existing one is there a char limit?
*do I need to create a new certificate and add the bundle to apple developer center? with a new app id?

Comment: It seems possible to add a much longer suffix to the Bundle ID by editing the *-Info.plist . (I just tried this with a duplicated Target in a test project).  You don't need a new certificate, and Xcode should be able request and download a new provisioning file containing the new Bundle ID semi-automatically.